# two queries returning different data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two queries below, which to me are the same so should return the same results. However they do not, the bottom query is not returning any data but I can't see why?

query below return the correct data

```
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = 'abc4' and myDate >= '2016-04-13'
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

The query below returns zero rows although I don't see why its the same query to me as the above one.

```
declare @myF nvarchar, @FromDate date
set @myF = 'abc4'
set @FromDate = '2016-04-13'
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = @myF and myDate >= @FromDate
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

**update**

the query below works, it seems like the trouble query doesn't like the @myF variable

```
declare @myF nvarchar, @FromDate date
set @myF = 'abc4'
set @FromDate = '2016-04-13'
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = 'abc4' and myDate >= @FromDate
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

Comment: Try varchar instead of nvarchar

Comment: provide the schema for the table `myTbl`

Comment: Well - in the first query you have the variable `myName = 'acb4'`- but in your second query you have `@myF = 'abc4'` Which of the two are correct?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen apologies thats a typo it should be abc4 - will update my post. In sql server I have the correct codes

Comment: @AkashAmin tried changing it to varchar, still the same issue though]

Comment: how about giving the datatype as nvarchar(50) to the same as your column in table.@mHelpMe

Comment: You need to provide the column size, like `@myF nvarchar (200)` other wise it will take the first character from the assigned value. The following query will explain that `DECLARE @myF NVARCHAR; SET @myF = 'abc4'; SELECT @myF;`

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks, just done that and it now works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set size for `NVARCHAR(4)`

```
DECLARE @myF NVARCHAR(4), @FromDate DATE
SET @myF = 'abc4'
```

Answer (score 1):

These two following queries are worked for me, and are equal.

Query #1:

```
SELECT  myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM    myTbl
WHERE   myName = 'abc4' and myDate >= '2016-04-13'
GROUP   BY myDate, myTicker
```

Query #2:

```
DECLARE @myF NVARCHAR(MAX), @FromDate DATE
SET     @myF        = 'abc4'
SET     @FromDate   = '2016-04-13'

SELECT  myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM    myTbl
where   myName = @myF AND myDate >= @FromDate
GROUP   BY myDate, myTicker
```

Answer (score 1):

the main reason is `Default Length` for `NVARCHAR` is `1`

So,your this query

```
declare @myF nvarchar, @FromDate date
set @myF = 'abc4'
set @FromDate = '2016-04-13'
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = @myF and myDate >= @FromDate
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

Returning the Query compare to the 1st Query like,

```
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = 'a' and myDate >= '2016-04-13'
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

That's why your both Query is not equal.

You need to specify the `Length` of your `NVARCHAR` Variable, like..

```
declare @myF nvarchar(MAX), @FromDate date
set @myF = 'abc4'
set @FromDate = '2016-04-13'
SELECT        myDate, myTicker, SUM(myUnits) AS mUnits
FROM          myTbl
where myName = 'abc4' and myDate >= @FromDate
GROUP BY myDate, myTicker
```

Then you'll get the expected result.